# Can player2 sends a notification to player1 using Parse, from the device?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications, backend

Is it possible to send a push notification from a device (player2), to another device (player1), when player2 has finished, using the "user" identifier in Parse? It would be like this :

player 1 plays, and sends his score
player 2 plays, checks if player1 has finished, if he has, player2 sends a notification to player1 using the "user" identifier of player1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push notifications are sent to devices, not users.  Devices are tracked via the installation table (PFInstallation object).  You need to add a column to your installations table in Parse so that it tracks the PFUser that is currently associated with that installation (device).  Then you can send a push message that targets installations where the current user is "player 1"

Example -

Whenever your user "logs in" to your game, you need to update the associated installation -

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
currentInstallation[@"currentPlayer"]=[PFUser currentUser];
[PFInstallation saveInBackground];
```

Then to send a message

```
 PFQUery *pushQuery=[PFInstallation query];
 [pushQuery whereKey:@"currentPlayer" equalTo:self.opponent];  // self.opponent is a PFUser
 [PFPush sendPushMessageToQueryInBackground:pushQuery
                                   withMessage:@"It's your turn"];
```

Comment: thanks Paulw11, would it be possible for you to show me a very simple example? I am not entirely sure how to proceed...

Comment: Thank Paulw11, sorry I did not know you answered. Thank you, this code makes it a bit more clear already!